# In which meaning is the adverb 'only' used here?

Tags: adverbs

From [the BBC](https://www.bbc.co.uk/learningenglish/english/course/towards-advanced/unit-7/session-3)

> British cycling's Olympic golden couple Jason Kenny and Laura Trott have ridden into the record books. They've now taken their collective gold medal tally to ten, winning five in Rio. Also on Tuesday 19-year-old Simone Biles became **only** the fourth competitor to win four gymnastic gold medals. She won the women's floor final.

There are two meanings on [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/tr/s%C3%B6zl%C3%BCk/ingilizce/only) and none of them helps for this sentence, I believe. It sounds like diminishing her success, but the news is written to appreciate her success.

Answer (score 2):

> Only: Used to show that there are very few of something. (Cambridge)

The commentator is saying that there are four people who have won four gymnastics gold medals (one of whom is Biles), and that four is a small number. This makes Biles's achievement more notable.